# Validation between two date rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a reservation/booking appointment, the user select two dates the starting date and the end date, how can I validate the date from the starting and the end date and also validate the dates in between those two dates **preventing the user from choosing again the starting, end date and the dates in between.**

Database

```
 date_start   |  date_end  
 14/11/2017      14/18/2017
```

View:

Date field for the dates

```
 <%= f.label :'date_start:' %>
 <%= f.date_field :date_start %>

 <%= f.label :'date_end:' %>
 <%= f.date_field :date_end %>
```

Model

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord 
 belongs_to: user
 validates :date_start, uniqueness: true
 validates :date_end, uniqueness: true
end
```

I used `validates :date_start, uniqueness: true` and `validates :date_end, uniqueness: true` but it only checks for the date start and the date_end but it does not check the dates in between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to have a separate method to hold the complex validation code. Use `validate :method_name` (without an 's') to call it.

The method should add error(s) to the object if it finds a problem.

Something like this:

```
validate :no_reservation_overlap

 scope :overlapping, ->(period_start, period_end) do
    where "((date_start <= ?) and (date_end >= ?))", period_end, period_start
 end


private

def no_reservation_overlap
  if (Reservation.overlapping(date_start, date_end).any?)
     errors.add(:date_end, 'it overlaps another reservation')
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You'll have to give me a better idea of what you're app is doing. What is a reservation and how does a user interact with it?

Comment: If it's a separate question you should should probably ask it as a separate question. And if this answer properly answered your original question you're welcome to click 'accept'

Answer (score 0):

```
     validate :check_overlapping 

     scope :overlaps, ->(date_start, date_end) do
        where "((date_start <= ?) and (date_end >= ?))", date_end, date_start
     end

     def check_overlapping 
       errors.add(:date_start, 'your error messages') if overlaps(date_start, date_end).any?
     end
```

end

Comment: Your scope is broken. It won't include partial overlaps

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks!