# Date range overlap per user rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I make the validation of the date per user using the code below? When I logged in as a different user I am not able to create a reservation with the same dates. I have user_id which references id in the table users. I want to be able to make the date_start and date_end unique to only the user and still be able to create the same dates with a different user.

Link for more information:
[Validation between two date rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276147/validation-between-two-date-rails)

```
validate :no_reservation_overlap

 scope :overlapping, ->(period_start, period_end) do
    where "((date_start <= ?) and (date_end >= ?))", period_end, period_start
 end


private

def no_reservation_overlap
  if (Reservation.overlapping(date_start, date_end).any?)
     errors.add(:date_end, 'it overlaps another reservation')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guess you could try to add this to your validate:

```
validate :no_reservation_overlap, :uniqueness => { :scope => :user_id }
```

Not sure if this works for you cause, but you should give it a try. Good luck!

EDIT:

I would suggest a different approach:

```
validate :no_reservation_overlap


def no_reservation_overlap
  if (Reservation.where("(? BETWEEN date_start AND date_end OR ? BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) AND user_id = ?", self.date_start, self.date_end, self.user_id).any?)
     errors.add(:date_end, 'it overlaps another reservation')
  end
end
```

Guess this should work, please give it a try

Comment: I encountered an error Unknown key: :uniqueness. Valid keys are: :on, :if, :unless, :prepend. Perhaps you meant to call `validates` instead of `validate`?

Comment: No, for custom validation is actually validate. Gonna update my answer with some suggest

Comment: This works for any new records you're trying to create, but you probably want to add `AND id != ?` where ? is `self.id` so that it excludes itself from that record search when making updates to an existing entry

Comment: This does not work for time intervals that contain each other. The validation allows creating an interval between April 2nd and 5the when an interval between April 3rd and 4th already exists.