# Date overlap unique per user rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I read this question [Date range overlap per user rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285635/date-range-overlap-per-user-rails)

How can you validate this per user using this code below:

```
def no_reservation_overlap
  if (Reservation.overlapping(date_start, date_end).any?)
     errors.add(:date_end, 'it overlaps another reservation')
  end
end
```

I used this code below which is the answer but it doesn't validate the conflict inbetween dates

booked june 2 to 3 created another booking 1 to 5 and it created how can i prevent that from happening?

```
validate :no_reservation_overlap


def no_reservation_overlap
  if (Reservation.where("(? BETWEEN date_start AND date_end OR ? BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) AND user_id = ?", self.date_start, self.date_end, self.user_id).any?)
     errors.add(:date_end, 'it overlaps another reservation')
  end
end
```

Comment: Re: `AND user_id = ?`, do you also have `user_id` column in reservations table? Try removing it and `self.user_id` from the query if not.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh yes I created a user_id column

Comment: @JagdeepSingh i tried removing the user_id other user can't create any reservation if I add user_id its unique to only a certain user

Comment: @JagdeepSingh It works but when I booked june 2 to 3 and created another booking june 1 to 5 and it created how can i prevent that from happening?

Comment: Try this: `Reservation.where("((:start_date BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) OR (:end_date BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) OR (:start_date < date_start AND :end_date > date_start) OR (:start_date < date_end AND :end_date > date_end)) AND user_id = :user_id", {start_date: self.date_start, end_date: self.date_end, user_id: self.user_id }).any?`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh it worked! Thanks

Comment: Be careful with the edge cases though. You will know those better than me. I mean booking for date 3 to 5 after 2-3 already booked. See where you want to replace `>` and `<` with `>=` and `<=` respectively. It depends on your need.

Comment: You may consider different DB structure, when every reservation period in split on separate days. I.E. for period of 13-15 June you'll have 3 records in the DB: `13, 14, 15`. In this case all you need is split incoming new period to days, and check if any of them exist in the table. If it does - then we have overlap, otherwise - free to commit reservation.

Instead of that ugly SQL query with multiple conditions, which looks bad both in terms of performance and readability.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh ok thank you very much

Comment: @nattfodd how do you suggest my db structure should be I placed a date_start and date_end column should the dates be only in a single column with multiple entries or record from a user?? thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @John separate table only responsible for storing reserved dates. So it may have only a few columns: `date, user_id`

And your query will be like: `valid_reservation = Reservation.where(date: [13, 14, 15], user_id: @current_user.id).none?`

Comment: @nattfodd appreciate the help I will implement your suggestion